# Wrapping a typedefed enum in cython

Tags: enums, cython

I would like to wrap the following code in cython:

```C
enum Status {GOOD, BAD};

typedef enum Status STATUS;
// note that the typedef means people dont
// have to write `enum Status` everywhere

// just returns `GOOD`
STATUS hello();
```

I wrote the following cython code in `c_library.pxd`:

```
cdef extern from "library.h":

  cpdef enum Status:
    GOOD,
    BAD

  ctypedef Status STATUS

  cpdef STATUS hello()
```

The module `c_library` now contains `c_library.GOOD`, `c_library.BAD`,
and `c_library.Status`, which behaves like an [enum](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/). However, the
return value of a call to function `hello` returns a plain int:

```
>>> c_library.hello()
0
>>> type(c_library.hello())
<class 'int'>
```

I would like the result to be wrapped in an enum of the same type as well.
I can change the cython file, but not the underlying C code. Is that possible?

Comment: This doesn't fix your problem but I think the `typedef enum` is a red-herring - it's useful in C to avoid writing `enum Status`, but there's no reason to do it in Cython really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a hiccup (minor bug?) of Cython, which decides to use `__Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__` for some reasons when wrapping `cdef`-function into a `def` function.

As a quick workaround I can propose to explicitly create a `Status`-enum:

```
%%cython
cdef extern from *:
    """
    typedef enum Status {GOOD, BAD} Status;

    // just returns `GOOD`
    Status hello() {return GOOD;}
    """
    cpdef enum Status:
        GOOD,
        BAD

    Status c_hello "hello"()

def hello():
    return Status(c_hello())
```

And now:

```
>>> type(hello())
<enum 'Status'>
```

Things maybe worth noting:

- [verbatim C-code](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#including-verbatim-c-code) is used, to make the example self-contained.
- Using `typedef enum X {...} X;` to pull enum's type-name from enum's name space into the name space of ordinary variables is a common practice (but obviously this is a matter of taste, so if you prefer `STATUS` - it is up to you). See the wording in C11-standard on different name spaces [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3) or this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/5769463) (even if it is about `struct`).
- `cname`-trick (i.e. `Status c_hello "hello"()`) is used, to be able to add a level of indirection and to keep the public interface of the module intact (i.e. `cpdef hello()`).
- However, when using `hello` as `cdef`-function I would probably use `c_hello` to avoid overhead of creating an enum - that is the reason `hello()` is defined as a `def`-function, so there is no confusion.

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow so much. Thank you very much for your help :) I ended up wrapping the call like you suggested.