# Making cython enums visible

Tags: enums, cython

This question is essentially a follow up regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047125/wrapping-a-typedefed-enum-in-cython). Specifically, I am wondering about enum visibility across shared modules.
Essentially, I would like to make a wrapped C enum part of a python API (using cython). The simplest way to wrap some existing C code would be a simple
`lib.pyx` (for the sake of simplicity I included the header verbatim)

```
cdef extern from *:
"""
typedef enum Status {GOOD, BAD} Status;
"""
cpdef enum Status:
    GOOD,
    BAD
```

If I compile this file into a shared library (say `lib.so`), I can use the enum directly, i.e. I can type `python3 -c "import lib; print(lib.Status)"` and see `<enum 'Status'>`, which is indeed the expected behavior.

Now assume that I would like to split the code into a header (aka `lib.pxd`)
containing the code from above as well as an implementation file (aka `lib.pyx`) `cimport`ing the header:

```
from lib cimport Status

def test():
    print Status.GOOD
```

I can again compile the project, however, the results are quite different.
I can access the function `test`, but `python3 -c "import lib; lib.test()"` just returns `0`, rather than `<Status.GOOD: 0>`.

What is more, `python3 -c "import lib; print(lib.Status)"` now gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'Status'
```

In short: The enum declared in the pxd file is not included in the final module, even though it is declared as `cpdef`.

Is this behavior intentional? Is there any way to include the declaration into the generated module?

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in Cython and worth reporting: When enum-definition is in pxd-File, the whole code concerning p-part of the definition isn't generated